# I need to affected row count in PostgreSQL Python or Django when run same query 2 or more time

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I need to get all affected row count in PostgreSQL . If i run update query then got right row count but if i run again same query then i also get same row count but i think second time no row affected so in this case row count will be 0.
Here is my simple code

```
import psycopg2

#db connection
conn = psycopg2.connect(
host="localhost",
database="test_db",
user="postgres",
password="123456"
)


#Setting auto commit false
conn.autocommit = True

#Creating a cursor object using the cursor() method
cursor = conn.cursor()

sql = "UPDATE test_table SET balance = 11 WHERE last_block = '14529343'"
cursor.execute(sql)
print("Rows returned = ",cursor.rowcount)
conn.commit()

conn.close()

#Closing the connection
```

After run this python script my current row affected is:

**Rows returned =  70**

second time also same output

**Rows returned =  70** but it is not correct, result will be 0

but if i run same update query then same result but in this case output will be 0.
This is screenshot
[image]

Comment: You are running an `update` that does not change anything used in the `where` clause. Since your `where` clause references only a specific `last block` but does not change that value any subsequent run of the same query will process **exactly the same rows**, giving the same count every time.  Perhaps you need to add the predicate `and balance <> ...`.

Comment: @Belayer but how can i get this result? any idea? it will be grateful help. Mainly main target, when i will run same query then no data will be updated so i will get affected  row 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement *no data will be updated* is wrong in fact **the exact same rows will be updated again, even though it is to the same value**. The value of column `balance` will not change but the rows will be updated.  The `update` statement does not look at existing values, to see that they have changed. It determines which rows are processed by conditions in the `where` clause only. Since you did not update the only criteria in the `where` and then ran again with the same `where` the same rows will be processed. You can see this by also selecting the [CTID](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html)

> The physical location of the row version within its table. Note that
> although the ctid can be used to locate the row version very quickly,
> a **row's ctid will change if it is updated** or moved by VACUUM FULL.

(Emphasis mine)

See [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=33681e3c95cf8d730cede1251de800ce). Updated is not the same a value changed.